Running a jar file with a java.exe, as a windows service possible without NSSM?
just wondering whether if it's possible to do the following or not.
I have not been able to replicate:
https://medium.com/@lk.snatch/jar-file-as-windows-service-bonus-jar-to-exe-1b7b179053e4
solution, specifically the with spaces.
However, the reason why I need to run a jar file as a service, is because I need to deploy this jar app via cloudformation on a Windows EC2 - via AWSCloudformation:init scripts, and therefore the service should be created upon boot and I need to ensure it's always running. I'm so far under the impression I have to create the service, and then the EC2 is started.
Here are some reproducible steps:

In Windows (C:), create a Dev folder (don't have to, can be anything).
Move your Java Folder to this Dev Folder
Here is my java code, which if it runs - to logs into the Java Folder.

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class IncrementAndLog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(0);
        String logFilePath = "C:\\Dev\\Java\\log.txt";

        // Create a new thread for logging
        Thread loggingThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Get the current value and increment by 10
                    int currentValue = value.getAndAdd(10);
                    // Log the current value to the file
                    logValue(logFilePath, currentValue);
                    // Wait for 30 seconds
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Start the logging thread
        loggingThread.start();
    }

    private static void logValue(String filePath, int value) {
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
             PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter)) {
            printWriter.println("Value: " + value);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



Create your jar file, however you want. This is what I did specifically:

javac IncrementAndLog.java 


Create a MANIFEST.MF file in the same directory as the java file.

Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Main-Class: IncrementAndLog 

Package everything into a jar:
jar cmvf MANIFEST.MF IncrementAndLog.jar IncrementAndLog.class


Now follow the following steps to create a service.

sc create IncrementServer binPath= "cmd /c C:\Dev\Java\jdk-11.0.7\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Dev\IncrementAndLog.jar" type= own start= auto error= normal

Now you can either manually start this service, or you can do it via:
sc start IncrementServer

What will happen is the application will log the increments every 3 seconds but the service will not be registered to "running", which is going to be an issue especially when ensureRunning is set true for that particular service for the EC2 instance, so multiple instances of this application will be triggered continuously.
So, is it possible to run a jar file truly as a windows service without relying on any sort of wrapper, and is there a reason why we can't? How does the service controller interact with the executables from the binPath?
Thanks!
Edit:
The error message I get is:
"Windows could not start the IncrementServer service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

So, is it possible to run a jar file truly as a windows service without relying on any sort of wrapper Almost certainly not. If you think about it, the wrappers wouldn't exist otherwise, would they? afaik Windows services have to respond to key control methods, for starting, stopping etc. How is your Java app, being run by java.exe, going to do that?

@g00se So, therefore I can’t interact with ServiceController without having C# wrapper right, in fact nothing can interact with it unless it’s explicitly defined to interact with it.

You need a wrapper yes, but they exist for Java too

What about this question is related to PowerShell? I none, please remove the powershell tag.

You cannot just launch any EXE or script as Windows Service unless they implement specific API callbacks. These callbacks would be handled for you by the various wrapper implementations like NSSM. It is possible to use Foreign Memory API to implement the required callbacks within your own Java applications. See more info

I’ll mark this of as answered, since I’ve been told I need to implement specific API callbacks with the Service Controller, for it to actually work as a Service. Thanks everyone.
